# TypeError: ms is not a function (SOLVED)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im getting this error

TypeError: ms is not a function

Here is my code:

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const ms = import("parse-ms");

module.exports = {
    
        name: "daily",
        aliases: ["coins-system"],
        category: "economy",
        description: "Gives You 200 per day",
        usage: " ",
        accessableby: "everyone",
    run: async (client, message, args, db) => {
      let blacklisted = await db.get(`blacklisted_${message.author.id}`)
if (blacklisted) return message.channel.send('You cannot use this bot since you are blacklisted')
        let user = message.author;

        let timeout = 86400000;
        let amount = 150;
      let vip = await db.get(`vip_${message.author.id}`)
      if (vip) amount = 350

        let daily = await db.get(`daily_${user.id}`);

        if (daily !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - daily) > 0) {
            let time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - daily));

            let timeEmbed = new discord.EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription(`❌ You've already collected your daily reward\n\nCollect it again in ${time.hours}h ${time.minutes}m ${time.seconds}s `);
            message.channel.send(timeEmbed)
        } else {
            let moneyEmbed = new discord.EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription(`✅ You've collected your daily reward of ${amount} coins`);
            message.channel.send(moneyEmbed)
            db.add(`cash_${user.id}`, amount)
            db.set(`daily_${user.id}`, Date.now())


        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make it save to the quick.db database after the user collects their daily amount of coins

Answer (score 0):

The [docs state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-ms) that you should use:

```js
// ES Module
import parseMilliseconds from 'parse-ms';
```

So in your case, you could try:

```js
// CommonJS
(async () => {
  const { default: parseMilliseconds } = await import("parse-ms"); // dynamic
  console.log(parseMilliseconds(1222));
})();
```

Then use `parseMilliseconds` in places of `ms`.

Comment: `async import("parse-ms"); // dynamic` — I think you mean `await`, not `async` … but I don't think top level `await` is supported in Node.js CommonJS modules … and the docs say to use the **default** import and not a named import so destructuring the result makes things worse (both when using import and when using require).

Comment: Im still getting the error: parseMilliseconds is not a function

Comment: Whenever i try: const ms = require("parse-ms") i get this:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\DR\Desktop\CyberTech\node_modules\parse-ms\index.js from C:\Users\DR\Desktop\CyberTech\commands\daily.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\DR\Desktop\CyberTech\commands\daily.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DR\Desktop\CyberTech\commands\daily.js:2:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DR\Desktop\CyberTech\index.js:19:18) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Comment: @MertonSupport don't use require in Node version 14+. Just use the dynamic import, if your module is CommonJS. See the updated snippets. I verified both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

On line 2 you have a [Dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import). These return a **promise**, not the value being imported.

You're writing a CommonJS module. You know the module you want to import at compile time.

<del>Don't use a dynamic import. Use `require`, just as you did on line 1.</del>

> Whenever i try: const ms = require("parse-ms") i get this: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\DR\Desktop\CyberTech\node_modules\parse-ms\index.js from C:\Users\DR\Desktop\CyberTech\commands\daily.js not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\DR\Desktop\CyberTech\commands\daily.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules. at Object. (C:\Users\DR\Desktop\CyberTech\commands\daily.js:2:12) at Object. (C:\Users\DR\Desktop\CyberTech\index.js:19:18) { code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' }

You're stuck with using a dynamic import.

Since these return a promise, you have to handle that promise. Since it is a CommonJS module you can't use top level await.

You can use `then`:

```js
import('parse-ms').then(parseMs => {
    const ms = parseMs.default;
    // Rest of your code goes here
});
```

… or wrap your code in an `async` IIFE.

---

I'd strongly consider moving to using [standard JavaScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) instead of CommonJS modules if you are going to depend on third-part standard JavaScript modules.